# Same services for several Angular 4 projects

Tags: angular

I am working on three different projects for a client, each one will be at a different server but the three of them share a lot of functionality.

I have this basic folder structure:

/company

--project1

--project2

--project3

So I tried to put a shared folder (with the services) at the same company directory as the three projects and reference the services going up a couple directories on the app module.

The files are successfully found by my module but it seems that those services must be inside the app/src folder, as an error emerges telling me that angular/core is missing.

This is the basic way I am defining my services:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Headers, Http } from "@angular/http";
import { AppSettings } from "../app.settings";
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Injectable()
export class RoutesService {
}
```

So I presume, it is breaking when it is trying to find Injectable into @angular/core

What do you guys recommend for accomplishing this?

Comment: If the app is hosted on different servers you'll want to treat each app individually.

Comment: I know, but maybe during development, it will be best if the app access the same services.

Comment: Maybe you should create separate module (lib) with your services and include it in each project

Comment: As @AntonLee said, you should create a separate module and that should be the best choice for production, however, for development you can get away with creating a `symlink` of your folder in one of your projects and the other projects. 
I've been working on developing a UI library for Angular and [this yeoman generator](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library) seems like the best choice as a starting point.